# Running Spring Boot container fails with File not found exception for hadoop-core-1.2.1

Tags: hadoop, spring-boot

This question has been posted before but I am not sure if it was ever resolved. I am facing exactly the same issue as (19608050 - same title). I am using spring-boot-started-web:1.1.0.RC1 ,spring-data-hadoop 1.0.2.RELEASE and hbase 0.94.3. I can see the hadoop-core-1.2.1 jar under the  lib\ in the jarred file which I deploy.

I have a small sample project which I posted on: https://github.com/klopes/test-spring-boot-hadoop.git. It compiles (and unit tests worked successfully) but it fails to deploy.

If I start the app by clicking on the main class in my IDE, it runs without any exceptions and the jar is loaded, also gradle runBoot works just fine. Seems like a spring boot class loader bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a very old version of Spring Boot. Your app runs for me with Spring Boot 1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, at least the context starts with no errors. There are no test cases so I'm not sure if it's actually working though.

Comment: Hi Dave - I updated the code to the bare minimum  and tried using the snapshot build as suggested. When I use the snapshot I get the error: IllegalStateException: Cannot find template location: class path resource [templates/] (please add some templates, check your Velocity configuration, or set spring.velocity.checkTemplateLocation=false) When I use the RC1 build as I was doing before I get the FileNotFoundException which I mentioned. I tried deploying both with tomcat and jetty - same error . There are no unit tests as the system fails at deploy time. (HBaseQueryHelper line 23)

Comment: (There are just two files for testing HBaseQueryHelper and AssetMain all other files are redundant)

Comment: It deploys with 1.1 ... I had to set spring.velocity.checkTemplateLocation:false in application.properties. Now I can proceed with my tests. Thanks Dave

Comment: If you're not using Velocity why is it on the classpath (just asking)? I guess it's a Hadoopism. Good to hear it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {VelocityAutoConfiguration.class})
```